# How to apply my own colormap in the fragment shader?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I have a given image img (**16 bits gray-level image whose values range from 0 to 65535**) and a colormap colormap_file which is a **8 bits RGB 256*256 pixels** image.

Thus, thanks to such a colormap I am able, for all pixels in the valueImage, to assign a (R, G, B) triplet.

Currently, it is done in pure Python through this function:

```
def transcodeThroughColormap(img, colormap_file):
    colormap = np.array(Image.open(colormap_file))
    flat_colormap = colormap.flatten()

    idx = img
    i = np.floor(idx / 256)
    j = idx - (i * 256)
    R = flat_colormap[(3 * (i * 256 + j)).astype('int')]
    G = flat_colormap[(3 * (i * 256 + j) + 1).astype('int')]
    B = flat_colormap[(3 * (i * 256 + j) + 2).astype('int')]


    rgbArray = np.zeros(shape=(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3))
    rgbArray[..., 0] = R
    rgbArray[..., 1] = G
    rgbArray[..., 2] = B


    return rgbArray
```

However, I would like to apply such a colormap but in my fragment shader.

Thus, I wonder I will have to use two sampler2D in my fragment shader but I do not how to achieve the same result as in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I past the answer I got from the OpenGL forum:
One option:

```
uniform usampler2D image_tex;
uniform sampler2D color_map;

in vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    uint value = texture(image_tex, texcoords).x;
    uvec2 uv = uvec2(value / 0x100, value % 0x100);
    vec4 color = texelFetch(color_map, uv, 0);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Note that the image texture needs to be of unsigned integer type, i.e. GL_R16UI. Magnification and minification filters need to be GL_NEAREST (linear interpolation isn't meaningful for integer values).

If the values in the image texture represent a continuous range and the colour map is continuous, then you could use a normalised format (i.e. GL_R16) for the image texture and use a 1-D texture for the colour map (however a size of 65536 isn't guaranteed to be supported, so you may need to down-sample the colour map). E.g.

```
uniform sampler2D image_tex;
uniform sampler1D color_map;

in vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    float value = texture(image_tex, texcoords).x;
    vec4 color = texture(color_map, value);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Or you could use a buffer texture for the colour map (a size of 65536 is guaranteed to be supported), which avoids the need to split the value into row and column. E.g.

```
uniform sampler2D image_tex;
uniform samplerBuffer color_map;

in vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    float value = texture(image_tex, texcoords).x;
    int idx = int(round(value * 0xFFFF));
    vec4 color = texelFetch(color_map, idx, 0);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

[Link to the topic on OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/newreply.php?do=newreply&p=1281557)